# Prove by mathematical induction that $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2^n-1} > \frac{n}{2}$

Tags: induction

1)Base of induction **n=2** : $${1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}>\frac{2}{2}}$$
2)Assuming right for **n=k** $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2^k-1} > \frac{k}{2}$$ and now need to prove that right for 
**n=k+1**
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2^k-1}+\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^k+1}+...+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}-1} > \frac{k+1}{2}$$
After simlifiying that we get to this
$$\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^k+1}+...+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}-1}>\frac{1}{2}$$ any hints about further steps?

Comment: The title and the question are different.

Comment: This formula is different to the one in your title. Can you write it in summation form so we can easily see the term by term pattern?

Comment: not true for $k=1$.

Comment: Don't you need to show that $$\frac1{2^k}+\frac1{2^k+1}+...+\frac1{2^{k+1}\color{#C00000}{-}1}>\frac{1}{2}$$ instead?

Comment: @robjohn yeah, my mistake

Comment: The previous inequality needs a similar fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** To show
$$
\frac1{2^k}+\frac1{2^k+1}+...+\frac1{2^{k+1}-1}>\frac12
$$
count the number of terms and look at the smallest term.

Comment: so like $$\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^k+1}+...+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}-1}>\frac{2^k}{2^{k+1}-1}$$ and from there divide it by $2^k$

Comment: Well, $\ge$, but can you show that $\frac{2^k}{2^{k+1}-1}\gt\frac12$? Oh, you mean divide *both numerator and denominator* by $2^k$. Yeah.

Comment: if divide by $2^k$ i get $\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2^k}}$, as $2-\frac{1}{2^k} < 2 $ then it workes just fine i guess

Comment: Perhaps simpler is to note that each of the $2^k$ terms is $\gt\frac1{2^{k+1}}$.